# Brasero/K3b say: "no disc present". How to burn on my blank DVD?

Tags: dvd, burning

I have a [Gateway E-4100](http://support.gateway.com/s/PC/E4100_Series/2800417/2800417nv.shtml) desktop computer with Ubuntu 12.04 installed. I'm trying to burn files to a blank DVD using the internal DVD/CD burner (of which I'm sure is the original that came with the PC).

I would expect Ubuntu to pop up a message whenever I insert a blank DVD in the drive, as that happens with blank CDs. Read-only or non-blank DVDs are working properly, however, for my blank DVD it seems that the drive or Ubuntu doesn't recognize it.

Burning applications Brasero and K3b report as if there's no disc present.

`dmesg` output for my CD/DVD drive:

```
[ 2.528310] ata2.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-STDVD-ROM GDR8161B, 0040, max UDMA/66
[ 2.528319] ata2.01: ATAPI: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GMA-4020B, A105, max UDMA/66
[ 2.569345] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM HL-DT-ST DVD-ROM GDR8161B 0040 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 2.580569] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[ 2.580785] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 2.586841] scsi 1:0:1:0: CD-ROM HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GMA-4020B A105 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 2.592719] sr 1:0:1:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
```

How can I burn to this DVD in Ubuntu?

Comment: What makes you think it's not recognized? What application are you using to burn? What exactly did you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: Whenever I put in a CD, either a blank or a full one, or a DVD that isn't a blank (sorry I'm not better with terminology), I get a screen asking what to do with the CD or DVD. But when I put a blank DVD in the drive, nothing happens. I've tried burning with both Brasero Disk Burner or K3B disk burner. In both burners it says there is no disk in the drive to burn to (or something like that)

Comment: Things to check: 1) is it a DVD burner or just CD/DVD combo for only CD-recording? The [E-4100](http://support.gateway.com/s/PC/E4100_Series/2800417/2800417nv.shtml) seems to be *very* old and I think DVD burners were not mainstream at that time. Please post the output of `dmesg | egrep '(CD|DVD)'` from a terminal. 2) not all blank media is compatible with all drives. Did you try another type of blank media? 3) Does the same blank disc work in another burner? 4) Is there a firmware update available for you drive to support more media?

Comment: Here are the results you asked for:

Comment: john-hill@john-hill-E-4100:~$ dmesg | egrep '(CD|DVD)'
[    2.528310] ata2.00: ATAPI: HL-DT-STDVD-ROM GDR8161B, 0040, max UDMA/66
[    2.528319] ata2.01: ATAPI: HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GMA-4020B, A105, max UDMA/66
[    2.569345] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVD-ROM GDR8161B 0040 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.580569] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
[    2.580785] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    2.586841] scsi 1:0:1:0: CD-ROM            HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GMA-4020B A105 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[    2.592719] sr 1:0:1:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
john-hill@john-hill-E-4100:~$

Comment: It says it is a DVD multi recorder.  I tried a blank CD and it worked. The same blank DVD worked in two other computers.

Comment: This is a **really old** one, it's just double speed. Are you by chance using a DVD+R? It can only burn DVD-R media according to [the specs](http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/lg4020/index.html). Either way, I think your blank disc is simply not compatible with your drive. A drive of 10(!) years old is simply too old for some newer media. Oh, and `A105` is an old firmware too. I believe this has nothing to do with Ubuntu now.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a *really* old optical drive there. It's one of the first DVD burners introduced. I believe this the reason for why your drive isn't recognizing the blank media, is that it's incompatible with your drive. I also believe it's not related to Ubuntu, unless you can state it works in another operating system.

Here are some options:

- Make sure you have a blank DVD-R (*minus sign*), not DVD+R.

  It's hard to retrieve the 'official' specifications of this drive nowadays, but it seems it's only capable of *writing* DVD-R, and only *reading* +R, according to [this site](http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/lg4020/index.html).
- Try upgrading the firmware.

  The firmware `A105` seems not to be the latest one available. The official download site seems not to be available anymore, but I see traces of `A109` versions on the web. Try to upgrade the firmware if you can still find an official source and tool to do so.
- Try buying media rated for lower speeds.

  Media rated for lower speeds may have older, traditional dye types that your drive support better.
- Consider buying a newer drive.

  Newer types, second hand, should be fairly cheap and will save you a lot of headache.